# Where are Qt libraries and source installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, qt

I need to [manually build a Qt plugin](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/sql-driver.html#qsqlite). No problem on Linux and Windows, but I cannot determine where in the world Qt installed the source on my Mac. The [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/install-mac.html) indicates that the path is /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.2, but I'm pretty sure that's out of date. In any case, there's nothing there on my machine.

I searched in Finder for `sqlite.pro` (the project I need to build) and it came up with zero hits. Is it hidden? Does the Mac SDK not come with the source (even though it is larger than both the Linux and Windows downloads?)

**EDIT:** Nevermind; this was user error. I forgot that I had downloaded the libraries-only on the Mac. I used the full SDK on the other machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the pre-build Qt binary packages come with source files. You need to download the source code package and [built](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/install-mac.html) it yourself.

Comment: You're totally right; this was user error. I downloaded the full SDKs on the other platforms, but needed the separate Cocoa library download on the Mac. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Start building with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

That should do it.